# Discord Python bot commands not responding

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

basically i have no idea why this code is not working, ive tried using on_message and that works so long as i dont include and if statement to filter for the messages with the prefix at the start. so i scrapped that, this code worked a few months ago with a different bot i made and ive ended up scrapping all the other stuff i was doing and bringing it down to the bare basics because i cant figure out why the bot doesnt recognise messages starting with the prefix.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
TOKEN = "Token_here"

@bot.command(name='tst')
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send('testt')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('Successful login as {0.user}'.format(bot)) 


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

ive tried print('Test') debugging aswell see below

```
@bot.command(name='tst')
async def test(ctx):
  print('Test")
```

then in discord typing the !test command still does nothing and the terminal also remains empty other than the on_ready result of

```
Successful login as botname#0001
```

i have no idea whats going on honestly

Comment: im running this in VS code if that makes any difference

Comment: You said you typed `!test`, but your command is `!tst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be causing your problems. I fixed the issue by enabling intents for the bot. This also must be done on the developer portal. https://discord.com/developers/applications

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

you also don't need the name parameter in the command decorator. It can just be written as :

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('testt')
```

Comment: `Intents.all()` already includes `members` so it's pointless to explicitly set `members` to `True` on the next line. `all()` is everything, as the name suggests. Also, refrain from using `all` when you don't need to. Subscribe to the intents that you actually _need_.

Comment: thank you i was unaware that i had to enable intents this has fixed the problem and the bot can now respond to commands and read message content.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```py
bot= commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

```py
@bot.command()
async def test():
    await ctx.channel.send("Test successful")
```